# get Total results from facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get total records count of posts for particular date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139574/how-to-get-total-records-count-of-posts-for-particular-date)

I am using facebook api [graph api] to retrieve posts from facebook.
Is that possible to get the total number of records from api response?

Thanks in advance