# How to get total records count of posts for particular date

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I want to get the total record count of posts for a particular search term, and a particular date.

(I want to get the total record count for the last 3 days, individual for each day.)

For example, the search term is "Steve Jobs," and I want to get the total record count (or I can get all records in one page) for date November 13, November 14, November 15.

Answer (score -1):

use `count($whaturcounting)`

documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: Hi Liam Allan,
thanks for your reply.but i want to know is ==> how to get total number of records without paging through each and every page of response?

Comment: the only other way i can think of is to add a limit to your api call eg: `$facebook->api("/me/comments?limit=2500");` that will broaden the results returned by api response

Comment: yes we can certainly limit that but it will not return exactly 2500 result.it will be surely less than 2500 and this difference may be bigger. So i want to know that , is that possible to know total number of results returned from facebook?